# How to pass variables to pandoc for use in HTML template?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pandoc

I use pandoc in VSCode to generate HTML files from Markdown files.

I use the following htmlOptString in VSCode:

```
"pandoc.htmlOptString": "-s -f gfm -t html5 --template=pandoc-template.html"
```

I don't want to have to change that line every time I render a document.

I do not understand how I can use metadata to pass information like author, title or more, from the MD file.

For example the following does not create the $title$ variable:

```
---
title: test
...
```

In my template the title element id rendered as empty

```
<title>$title$</title>
```

How do I create variables from the markdown file?

I also tried using a YAML metadata file to no effect.

### UPDATE

#### Environment

- MacOS Sierra
- Pandoc 2.1.1
- Latest VSCode

I tried specifying the `yaml_metadata_block` extension in the pandoc command
My new htmlOptString is:

"pandoc.htmlOptString": "-s --from=gfm+yaml_metadata_block -t html5 --template=pandoc-template.html"

When I run the command from a terminal the result is the same, i.e. the title block is rendered in HTML and no $title$ variable is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc added support for this in version 2.13 (released on 2021-03-21).  Nowadays, it should be enough to update to the [latest version](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest) for this to work.

Comment: Yes! I found out by myself as well, but it's nice to have outside confirmation (and now I don't have to post the answer ;) ).